# Memory<Byte> conversion with minimal or no allocation?

Tags: c#, memory, type-conversion, allocation

I'm looking to convert a `Memory<Byte>` to some other type (double, int...) while trying to eliminate allocation (until the final place where the value goes).

I figure out how to get the value of a bit in a byte but I can't seem to figure out how to do it for a double or int. I want to avoid using .ToArray as it would perform a heap allocation.

[EDIT]
Also to make things even easier, I need to perform a byte swap prior to conversion.

```
var buffer = GC.AllocateArray<byte>(1024, true);
var bufferMem = buffer.AsMemory();
//Something put data in bufferMem

var boolValue = bufferMem
    .Slice(0, 1)
    .Span[0]
    .GetBit();


public static bool GetBit(this byte b, int bitIndex)
{
    return (b & (1 << bitIndex)) != 0;
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: How about `var d = BitConverter.ToDouble(bufferMem.Slice(0,sizeof(double)).Span);`?

Comment: This would work :) However, I need to perform a byte swap. Sorry I should have mentioned it.

Comment: I don't think it's an easy task. Why you don't want allocation?

Comment: I'm looking to create a high bandwidth and optimized UDP socket and to reduce allocation at a minimum would be the best. I'm trying to reduce allocation when un-packing the payload received.
As you said, I don't think there is an easy way to swap without allocation. ToArray it is.
Thank you for your help

Comment: you could have preallocated arrays and for each package use this array, instead of creating a new array for each package